# Ubuntu 19.04 Background and lockscreen image turns into white noise after sleep and wakeup

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, desktop-background

This question is related to [bug #1827314](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1827314) on Launchpad. As stated, the Ubuntu 19.04 lock screen and background is distorted by white noise when the computer is awakened from suspend. How may I proceed to troubleshoot it?  [image: my lock screen and background is distorted by white noise]

Comment: I took a pic of how the background looks. It is essentially white with colored pixels scattered over it. I replaced the picture as suggested to better illustrate how it looks.

Comment: TY, much more clear now. What is the make and model of the PC? Which video drivers are in use? Does it occur with an external monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot state what caused this issue to occur, however after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10 it is gone.